# Odd Firebug behavior with radio button

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug

The following is a very minor problem, I would just like to understand why this happens.

Create a html document that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {font-family: Arial;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />
</body>
</html>
```

Now open it in Firefox (I am using build 14.0.1) and right click the radio button to open a context menu.  From that menu select "Inspect Element with Firebug...", which will open Firebug with the HTML tab open and the radio button HTML code highlighted.

Now try and select the radio button.  It will be selected for a second but then it quickly deselects itself. Why?

I know if I remove that body style definition the above behavior will not happen or if I am in a different tab while Firebug is open (such as the "Console" tab) it won't happen or if Firebug isn't open it won't happen.

I know this is super minor and very situational I just like to at least have some idea of why this is.

Comment: +1 I tried it, and I seem to be having the same issue. It's most probably a bug in firebug. [You should file it](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/I_found_a_Firebug_Bug!#Reporting_the_problem).

Comment: I had the same bug happen when I tried the code. Adding anything else to the page, like text after it, seemed to make it clear up. You should report it to FireBug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have heard of this before,  my onlu suggestion is to report it to FireBug and for now keep trying until you find a work around. Maybe try wrap a form round it or add content round it?

Comment: I marked this as answered because I think the only way to find out why this happens is to report it to the Firebug team and hopefully they answer it.  I don't think anyone outside of the Firebug team would be able to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with firebug that is sadly still open

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5744

Annoyingly it creates a [heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) situation if you don't know about it, where you can't work out why radio buttons won't check for you.